# Determining whether a button is enabled or disabled (Silk4J)

Tags: java, sap-gui, silktest

I am testing a SAP GUI application and I need to find out whether a button is enabled or disabled.

I have read the [MicroFocus documentation for the SapButton class](http://documentation.microfocus.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.borland.silktest.silk4net.doc%2Flangref%2FSAP%2FSapButtonClass_ref.html), but I can't find a method like `getEnabled()`, `isEnabled()` or `getDisabled()` or `isDisabled()`.

How can I find out whether a button is enabled or disabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The enabled/disabled state is hidden behind the [Changeable property](http://documentation.microfocus.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.borland.silktest.silk4net.doc%2Flangref%2FSAP%2FChangeablePropertySapComponent_ref.html). Since the online documentation is for C#, this maps to `isChangeable()` in Java.

The `isChangeable()` does not only get the enabled state for buttons but also for comboboxes, checkboxes and potentially others.

IMHO the documentation

> Gets whether an object is changeable.

is a bit misleading.